# RSS image tag to display

Tags: php, rss

Im using this library to post an rss feed on my website.

The question i have is in the rss feed i have the image tag. How do i add this one image below to my feed?

Thanks

```
<pubDate>Thu, 10 Nov 2011 17:10:19 GMT</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Thu, 10 Nov 2011 17:10:19 GMT</lastBuildDate>
<ttl>15</ttl>
<image>
<title>press conference</title>
<url>
http://www.website.com/images/image.jpg
</url>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your library (or you?) are violating the RSS2 specs. [The specs say:](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#ltimagegtSubelementOfLtchannelgt)

> `<image>` is an optional sub-element of `<channel>`, which contains
>   three required and three optional sub-elements.

Those three required sub-elements are:

1. `<url>`: specifies the URL to a GIF, JPG or PNG image.
2. `<title>`: is the equivalent to the `alt`-attribute in HTMLs
   `<img>`-tag
3. `<link>`: is the URL to your site which should (when the RSS-file is
   rendered) be the target for the link on your image.

However, you might also want to specify a width, height and description for the image (descriptions can be found in the specs, linked above).

---

So a valid RSS-file (just the `<image>`-part) should look something like this:

```
<image>
  <title>press conference</title>
  <url>http://www.website.com/images/image.jpg</url>
  <link>http://www.website.com</link>
</image>
```